# node.js How to communicate between modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm fairly new to node.js and recently started to make some modules. However I've come to a point where communication between modules is required. Since this is not a problem I've encountered in the past I'm stuck with finding a clean solution.

This is the boilerplate I currently got (Left out some checks to make the code a bit smaller). The basic idea atm is joining any irc channel given by an http post.

### bot.js

```
//Include services

var Webservice    = require('./Webservice');
var Ircservice    = require('./Ircservice');

//Create service instances

var webservice = new Webservice();
var ircservice = new Ircservice();

//Initialize services

webservice.init(1337);
ircservice.init('alt-irc.snoonet.org', 80, 'User');

//Handle events

ircservice.on('irc-registered', function(msg){
    console.log(ircservice.connected);

    ircservice.joinChannel('#testchannel')
});

ircservice.on('irc-join', function(channel){
    console.log('Successfuly joined: ' + channel);
});

webservice.on('web-join', function(streamer){
    ircservice.joinChannel('#' + streamer);
});
```

### Webservice.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var util = require('util');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

var Webservice = function(){
    EventEmitter.call(this);
};

Webservice.prototype.init = function(port){
    app.listen(port, function () {
      console.log('Webserver listening on ' + port);
    });

    this.initRoutes();
};

Webservice.prototype.initRoutes = function(){
    var self = this;

    //join a irc-channel
    app.post('/join', function (req, res) {
        var streamer = req.body.name;

        self.emit('web-join', streamer);
        res.send('Received')
    });

};

util.inherits(Webservice, EventEmitter);

module.exports = Webservice;
```

### Ircservice.js

```
var irc = require('irc');
var util = require('util');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var Ircservice = function(){        
    EventEmitter.call(this);
}

Ircservice.prototype.init = function(server, port, nick){       
    this.client = new irc.Client(server, nick, {
        port: parseInt(port)
    });

    this.initListerners();
};

Ircservice.prototype.initListerners = function(){
    var self = this;

    this.client.addListener('message', function (from, to, message) {
        console.log(from + ' => ' + to + ': ' + message);
    });

    this.client.addListener('join', function(channel, nick, message){
        self.emit('irc-join', channel);
    });
};

Ircservice.prototype.joinChannel = function(channel){       
    this.client.join(channel, null);
};

util.inherits(Ircservice, EventEmitter);

module.exports = Ircservice;
```

---

This example works perfectly, but as you can see the communication between my webservice and ircservice is handled by the bot.js. While this is perfectly fine for this example, I cannot use this method whenever I want.

Let say in the future I want to keep a list in my ircservice of all channels he has joined and display this through a webpage. I could keep a local array on my ircservice and on the join event add that channel to the array. But how do I continue on the webservice end. I can write an endpoint '/getchannels' but my webservice itself is not aware of the ircserver to get the channels (ircservice.getChannels or something similar) and firing an event in my web request doesn't feel like the way to go.

One solution that came up in my mind was passing the instances of the services to each other like webservice.setIrcservice(ircservice) and the other way around  in the bot.js. But this feels like dirty code and a hard depency.

So how can I communicate between modules when I need data instantaneously and events are no option?

Comment: Why not have one encapsulate the other? Seems to make sense for webservice to contain ircservice, and call methods to get data or trigger irc actions, and bind to events whenever you need something from irc to do something in the webservice. Why are events not an option?

Comment: Encapsulating can be a solution for this example. In the end the program will be much more complex with alot more services.

Comment: In that case not all communication can't be resolved through encapsulating.

When you need data from multiple services you need to fire multiple events to get your data. In the end you must check if all events are complete before rendering the data. Is there no easier way except events or is the 'node way' of doing things?